# Symfony MongoDb can't retrieve new field values

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have added new entry in Document description

```
/**
 * @MongoDB\Field(type="string")
 */
protected $city;
```

Then let Doctrine generate entities. Now newly created records have new field "city" with values as expected. However I can see these values only in mongo console. In Doctrine output they are allways set to "null". The entity entries seems correct

```
public function getFirstName()
{
    return $this->firstName;
}

/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string $city
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}
```

I have repository

```
public function allQuery($cat)
{
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->sort('createdAt', 'DESC');

    if ($cat) {
        $q->field('category.$id')->equals(new \MongoId($cat));
    }
    return $q;
}
```

And service

```
function addAllPager($perPage = 10, $cat)
{
    return $this->_addPager($this->repo()->allQuery($cat), $perPage);
}
```

In Controller

```
    $helper = $this->get('appbundle.test.helper');
    $tests = $helper->addAllPager(10, $cat);
```

Symfony profiler shows me query `db.Test.find().sort({ "createdAt": -1 }).limit(10).skip(0)`. Dumped Contents of $tests

```
#firstName: "John"
#city: null
```

What I am missing?

**EDIT**

Cache clearing with `php bin/console cache:clear` solved the problem. 
`php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:cache:clear-metadata` was not enough. Thank you `malarzm`.

Comment: Please clear your cache and restart Apache, such thing usually stems from not updated hydrators or cached metadata which was not updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 8 months after the question has been asked but had the same issue and fought with doctrine for a while. I am using Symfony 3 and I tried `php bin/console doctrine:mongodb:cache:clear-metadata` with no luck.

I finally ran the command `php bin/console cache:clear` or just delete the cache with this command `sudo rm -rf var/cache` and that fixed the issue.